# How to restructure/reformat Pandas dataframe containing images to be fed into Tensorflow's model.fit()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

In preprocessing a set of images to be fed into a Tensorflow convolutional neural network, I have created a Pandas dataframe with two columns.

The first contains 13200, 1/255-rescaled images(specifically their file paths to their respective train/test and class directories) filled into the dataframe such that, barring the error I am about to show, should be ready for a traditional sklearn test_train_split. The second column contains the class labels associated with each image. Here is what the dataframe looks like:

[(the dataframe)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiwO3.jpg)

Now, the error. While in checking the shape of an individual image I get the proper (-,-,-) dimensions, in checking the shape of my X_train dataframe as a whole the output I receive is (10560, ). As is true of the CIFAR-10 dataset, I am expecting a shape of (10560, 150, 150, 3), to fully represent the dimensions of my dataset. No matter what I input as the input_shape for my Conv2D layer, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [32, 1]
```

So I believe the right question to ask in order to resolve this error is how do I restructure and/or change the image inputs in column 1 so that the correct shape of the dataset is yielded to comply with the model fit?

Answer (score 0):

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D layer expects input of shape `4+D` tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols)` if data_format='channels_first' or `4+D` tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (rows, cols, channels)` if data_format='channels_last'.
Make sure your X_train be shape of 4D.